# Django model foreign key issue

Tags: django

I'm using model like this:

```
class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    group = models.ForeignKey(Category.objects.filter(group__category__name='foo'))
```

issue is getting error `django.core.exceptions.AppRegistryNotReady: Models aren't loaded yet.`

Answer (score 0):

You should pass model as ForeignKey argument not a queryset.
If you need to restrcit foreign key choices try to use [limit_choices_to](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.limit_choices_to):

```
group = models.ForeignKey(Category, limit_choices_to={'name'='foo'})
```